# Sort an array of objects by the date where the date is the key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

So consider the following image of an array of objects where its `date: array`

[image]

It's clear to see that this array is out of order, there are tons of examples of sorting an array of objects where there is a date key with a value of the date. But there seem to be no example wheres I can sort this array of objects where the key of the object is the date.

**Ideas?**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-array-by-a-date-property) is the closest answer I could find but again my date, as you can see if the key of the object.

Comment: Can you post the array in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to georg's way.

```js
data = [
    {[new Date(2014, 1, 2)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2013, 2, 3)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2016, 3, 4)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2014, 4, 5)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2015, 1, 6)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2016, 2, 2)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2014, 3, 3)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2015, 4, 4)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2013, 5, 5)]: 1}
];

data.sort((a, b) =>
          Date.parse(Object.keys(a)[0]) -
          Date.parse(Object.keys(b)[0]))

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```js
data = [
    {[new Date(2014, 1, 2)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2013, 2, 3)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2016, 3, 4)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2014, 4, 5)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2015, 1, 6)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2016, 2, 2)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2014, 3, 3)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2015, 4, 4)]: 1},
    {[new Date(2013, 5, 5)]: 1}
];

result = data
    .map(obj => [Date.parse(Object.keys(obj)[0]), obj])
    .sort((x, y) => x[0] - y[0])
    .map(x => x[1]);


console.log(result);
```

This uses a technique called "decorate-sort-undecorate" oder [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).